# PSEXEC command is not working consistantly

Tags: psexec

I have 2 servers and both are Windows 2003. I am trying to connect from server A to B using PSEXEC. It works fine sometime and its not working few hours later..

However when restart server B then its getting connected. Please advise how to resolve this issue without restarting it

Comment: Can anyone have answer pls?

Comment: I have this issue as well, I try to unshare a folder and re-share it with different permissions and it doesn't always work.